# XSLT 1.0 cannot select variables in xsl:value-of select

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-variable

I try to transform a piece of XML that is generated by multiple sources. If I enter the text directly into the value-of select statement it works as intended. But as soon as I try to use variables it won't work any more.

If I use variables in the xsl:for-each statement it works fine too. This is the XSL that works fine

```
<xsl:variable name="crm_acc" select="account" />
<xsl:variable name="nav_acc" select="kontakt" />
<xsl:variable name="crm_fname" select="firstname" />
<xsl:variable name="nav_fname" select="fname" />

<TreeView>
  <xsl:for-each select="$crm_acc | $nav_acc">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item">
      <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:" >
        <xsl:value-of select="firstname | fname" />
      </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TreeView>
```

But if I use variables inside of xsl:value-of select it just doesn't work as specified in the next code block. I tried a lot of combinations e.g. using only one variable with "firstname", "firstname | fname", trying to concat(...) the text etc...

```
<TreeView>
  <xsl:for-each select="$crm_acc | $nav_acc">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Item">
      <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:" >
        <xsl:value-of select="$crm_fname | $nav_fname" />
      </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TreeView>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
  <account system="CRM">
    <firstname>test1</firstname>
  </account>
  <account system="CRM">
    <firstname>test2</firstname>
  </account>
  <kontakt system="NAV">
    <erstername>nav1</erstername>
  </kontakt>
</root>
```

Only once I got a result, as I specified "account/firstname" in the variable. But this way I always got the value of the first element only in every for-each iteration. It seems as if it looses the context when specifying variables (that the processor is currently inside an "account" entity and should select "firstname as a subnode).

I read that something changed in the value-of select statement from XSLT 1.0 to 2.0 but I do not fully understand what the difference is (I am pretty new to XSLT).

How do I have to specify the XSL to get it to work?

**Update**: The expected output as in code block 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Header="Xaml Accounts Tab">
  <TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="CRM">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">test1</TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="CRM">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">test2</TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="NAV">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">nav1</TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
</TabItem>
```

**Edit**: What I should have mentioned is that these template(s) will/can get modified so it would be easier if all the "variables" are in one place. It could be that the target is not named "contact" but something else and changing it in the whole document is error prone and redundant. Also these variables are used in another process read by a XmlReader. I try to keep hassle of configuration and redundancy as low as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches you might want to explore: one uses a variable to store all possible **names** of an element you might wish to call upon; the other assumes that the **position** of an element within its parent is known, therefore the name is of no importance.

The following stylesheet shows both methods, the former for the parent element, the latter for the *firstname* child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="CRM">
    <name>account</name>
    <name>kontakt</name>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<TreeView>
    <xsl:for-each select="root/*[local-name()=exsl:node-set($CRM)/name]">
        <TreeViewItem Header="{@system}">      
            <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:" >
                <xsl:value-of select="*[1]" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
  </xsl:for-each>
</TreeView>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know I can use "Extension" without installing them. (At least I think that is what is happening with EXSLT). I had to add `<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()=exsl:node-set($CRM_Props)/name]" />` instead of `*[1]` to get what I wanted (another variable with the subset of "sub-properties". Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the processor, but exsl:node-set() is supported by almost every one of them; in any case, there's a (more complex) method to make it work without the extension function, should you ever find yourself in the need.

Comment: Ok good to know. I use the standard .NET XsltCompiledTransform Class which only supports XSLT 1.0. As I just found out it must be next to pure luck as it only supports 2 functions from XSLT natively :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variables in XSLT are immutable. Treat them as constants. When you did

```
<xsl:variable name="crm_fname" select="firstname" />
```

You selected "firstname" in the *current* context. I suppose that code in a `<xsl:template match='root'>` context, so you selected "root/firstname". There is no such node, so the result is empty as expected.

When you call the variable in the for-each you are simply printing the contents of the variable, which is nothing.

It worked when you said the variable was `account/firstname` because that node exists, but since the variable is actually a constant, it contains the contents of the first match and any other attempts to change that value were ignored.

Comment: So when I write the text directly into the select statement I am in the for-each(contact) context, but if I use a variable I am in the root context? Yea I know XSL is not as "normal" programming languages, but in this case I do not fully understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT, you have to forget about any procedural paradigms you know. You should avoid `xsl:for-each` whenever inappropriate and write separate templates instead.

Likewise, there is no need to use variables in your case. That is, it's not impossible to use them but, as pointed out by @helderdarocha, you have to be aware of their immutability and the *context*.

In the stylesheet you show, it is likely that most of the variables are empty because the elements you select do not exist in that context. To select elements regardless of where in the hierarchy they are, begin an expression with `//`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Header="Xaml Accounts Tab">
         <TreeView>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </TreeView>
      </TabItem>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="account|kontakt">
      <TreeViewItem  Header="{@system}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </TreeViewItem>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="firstname|erstername">
      <TreeViewItem  Header="Firstname:">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </TreeViewItem>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         Header="Xaml Accounts Tab">
   <TreeView>
      <TreeViewItem xmlns="" Header="CRM">
         <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">test1</TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem xmlns="" Header="CRM">
         <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">test2</TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem xmlns="" Header="NAV">
         <TreeViewItem Header="Firstname:">nav1</TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
   </TreeView>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: The example I posted is pretty simple, it will get more complex and it would be good if I could use variables as I have to use them outside of the XSLT process as well. (So it would be nice if I do not have to specify those things twice or more times). What I do not understand is why "contact" -> "firstname" is not the same as "$contact" -> "$firstname" (where the content of these variables is "contact" and "firstname"). Why is this a different context in the latter case?

Comment: what I should have mentioned is that these template(s) will/can get modified so it would be easier if all the "variables" are in one place. it could be that the target is not named "contact" but something else and changing it in the whole document is error prone and redundant

Comment: My answer solves your question as it was an hour ago. You should avoid packing too much information into a single question. So, do not extend the original question with much more, but ask a new question that _builds upon_ the solution to this one.

Comment: In other words, study my answer to your inital question, use the insights to alter your XSLT code _before_ you ask a new question where you _isolate_ your new problem. It is not clear what you mean by `"contact" -> "firstname"` but this is something you can explain in a new question.

Comment: it is not a new problem, it is still the same. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the first place. And so I do not see how your answer answers (the intention) of my question at the moment. With "contact" -> "firstname" I meant the scope. "firstname" is executed inside of a "contact". in xpath: contact/firstname

Comment: @Kirschi I think the point you are missing here is this: when you set a variable to a node, the variable stores the node (or a reference to the node) - not the name of the node.

Comment: I see... thank you @michael.hor257k you were right, I thought it is the name that is referenced. This helped me in understanding the inner workings of XSL a bit more.